# Terminology for camera focus values

Tags: software, focus

I am a software developer writing a software interface for a Bosch mic 9000i camera. I have an interface to change the focus of the camera and I'm writing documentation for an end user. The numeric focus values that the camera accepts are 0-255. I've been referring to the value range as the magnitude. **What should I call a numeric focus value for a camera?**

When I increase the focus value, the camera shifts focus to closer objects, decreasing the number brings further objects into sharper focus. **Is there a better way to phrase this than 'Focus Near' and 'Focus Far'**?

Comment: Having written code for stuff like this I feel your pain. In my system there is a preset "near focus" button and "far focus" with a pair of in and out buttons. Adjust the focus using near and far. Then a long press on the "far focus" sets it, and a brief press recalls it. My boss always sets them the wrong way round - focusing on an object and then setting the wrong button and then gets confused. (Near & Far Focus buttons should just be called preset A & preset B)

Answer (score 8):

*Photographers* don't care about the 0 to 255 values, they care about the actual focal distance of the lens in real world units (i.e. metres in the vast majority of cases). If you are creating a product for photographers, you should find out how to translate arbitrary numeric values into real-world units and use those.

Comment: If you're _not_ creating a product for photographers, then the question is off-topic.

Comment: Agreed. Nobody other than the users of the software interface care about 0–255 limitations of computer number representation. They care about what the input _represents_. As a user (and even as a software developer), I want to input a useful real-world number, such as focus distance. The software library, API, driver, or whatever, should handle the conversion from human-useful numbers to system-specific digital values, IMO. I've written dozens of such types of specs, and used hundreds, and I always appreciate the ones that abstract the computer-oriented details away from real-world use cases.

Answer (score 3):

**Minimum and maximum focus (focal) distance.** As others have indicated, you'd be appreciated for indicating in a metric like feet or meters. Regardless, **increasing and decreasing** focus distance seems appropriate.

At the very least, you'll want to change 0 to be the minimum focus distance for that lens, and 255 the maximum.
According to [BH photo's specs for the model you mentioned](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1373857-REG/bosch_mic_9502_z30bvs_mic_ip_fusion_9000i.html), the range is 276 feet - infinity. The values between are an exponential function, so that probably 50 is roughly 2x your minimum distance, but you probably will want to know the exact function.

Comment: _"You'll want 0 to be the minimum focus distance for that lens, and 255 the maximum."_ The OP clearly indicates that the internal system he must deal with is the opposite: "decreasing the number brings further objects into sharper focus," so 0 is focus at infinity or as close to it as the system can get. I see no reason to bring the "0" through "255" numbers out to the user either way; a photographer wants to know the focus distance in meters (or possibly feet if he's so unfortunate as not to be familiar with metric).

Comment: "The values between are an exponential function" Are you sure? Typical linear focussing systems would give a hyperbolic function, assuming that the "focus values" correspond linearly to a displacement of the optics.

Comment: Good catch @cjs that OP is treating 0 as infinity. Since they are a software developer writing an interface for end user, I made more clear that the polarity should be flipped.

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff Admittedly I used the term exponential to refer to any changing rate of change, sorry for sloppy wording. Would a hyperbolic function suggest a different (kind of) rate of change than the example I had provided immediately after the quoted line?

Comment: The word you're looking for may be "non-linear".

Comment: @MarkK I'm not clear why the polarity should be flipped. Perhaps it's because I design software and systems as well as doing photography, but if there's going to be a "zero to ..." numerical interface, I find making 0 = focus at infinity much more sensible, because that's the constant endpoint. How close you can focus of course varies with each lens I use on my camera; some may go to "150" and others to "300" in whatever arbitrary units are used.

Comment: @cjs OP asks for a name for a continuum. My proposal is focus distance. Maybe an unnecessary change, but my thought is that 0 intuitively maps to "nearer" focal distances, and removing a negative mapping would improve usability. Fine enough if you think that '0 focus distance' intuitively maps to infinity. Note that we're not dealing with an unknown focal range, though; OP's stated model (and linked in my answer) has a fixed range of 270+ feet. At this point I think we're splitting hairs where OP's question could be refined, though.

Comment: I think that "focus distance" is a perfectly reasonable name. Where we differ is on two points. The first I that I think that the most "intuitive" unit for a distance measurement is meters/feet/infinity because that's what most camera lenses have used for over a hundred years and still use to this day. Look at any lens with writing on it and you'll usually find the minimum focus distance given in meters or feet, with the assumption that the maximum focus distance is infinity.

Comment: The second is that, if you're going to use something other than meters/feet/infinity, swapping around around the numerically fixed endpoints is particularly non-intuitive. It's so well accepted that every lens has a fixed endpoint of infinity focus on one end that many people don't even know that there exist lenses that can't focus to infinity, and these certainly are rarely sold. But every lens has a minimum focal distance of something greater than zero, and this value varies widely among lenses. (That's why they often write it on the lens.)

Comment: So your proposal that "0" is linked to a minimum focal distance that is different for each lens, and there's some varying value above that that's linked to the standard maximum focal distance for virtually all lenses, doesn't make much sense at all. Why should the distance that's virtually always infinity be a number that varies from system to system, and the number that changes from lens to lens always be 0 for each system?

Comment: @cjs, we don't disagree on your first point, and in part for the reasons you state; see the second sentence in my answer. Your second point is conditioned on the first one. If you're set on "0" == infinite distance, and "255" == 276 feet, then great. We know your vote. "50" will farther than "100", and so on.

Comment: When you say, "At the very least, you'll want to change 0 to be the minimum focus distance for that lens, and 255 the maximum" we are in strong disagreement there. The minimum focus distance should never be 0, under any circumstances. (0 cannot be a focus distance in m or ft because there is no such thing as an infinitely thin lens that would focus something sitting on the sensor. If one instead uses an arbitrary range not in m/ft—and perhaps not even linear with a m/ft scale—and rooted at 0, 0 for infinity makes the most sense for reasons I've described above.)

Comment: BTW, if you feel it's important that numbers get smaller as focus distance comes closer even when using an arbitrary scale, I would have no objection to using a range of 0 to _-n,_ especially where _n_ varies with different lenses or whatever.